# C++ Read Pipe into String

Tags: c++, char, popen, stdstring

I am writing a c++ program that executes shell commands. I am using the `popen()` function to run the commands. I would like my `exec` function to return `std::string` but I do not know how to read from a `FILE` into a string. Is there a way to do this without reading into a `char[]` first and then converting that into a string? If there are many which is the most efficient?

Comment: No, there is no way of reading directly from a `FILE` stream into a `std::string`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg so would the best solution be to read it into a `char*` and then convert that to a `std::string`?

Comment: Yes, either that or read character by character (with e.g. `fgetc`) and append to the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. The `popen()` function returns a pointer to a `FILE`. You cannot read from a `FILE` directly into `std::string`. You can however convert `char*` to `std::string` which appears to be the best solution in your case.

Answer (score -3):

It sounds like you could use `std::ifstream` --> http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: I must be missing something.  OP said he has a file that he wants to read into a string.  Where did this `FILE*` come from?

Comment: The OP uses [`popen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) to be able to read the output of an executing program. The `popen` function returns a `FILE*`. The OP also mentions that he/she don't know how to read from a `FILE` (the one returned by `popen`) into a string.

Comment: I guess the next question would be, is using `popen()` actually necessary if `std::ifstream` does the trick better?  Hard to say without knowing the full scope.

Comment: There are no stream classes in the standard C++ library that can read the standard output from a running program.